# Языки функционального программирования для изучения

Tags: функциональное-программирование

Заинтересовался функциональным программированием. Ничего подобного никогда не изучал. Какой язык функционального программирования, по вашему мнению, стоит изучать? Чтобы не был устаревшим, присутствовала какая-либо поддержка со стороны сред разработки, применение на практике, удобство, ну и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в ознакомительных целях, то лучше сперва рассмотреть не чисто функциональные языки (оставить [Haskell](http://haskell.org/) на десерт). Таких есть целая куча и лучше выбрать что вам ближе в зависимости от среды. Если прежде всего преследовать применение на практике, то следует обратить внимание на языки завязанные на JavaVM и .NET.

- [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/)
- [Clojure](http://clojure.org/)
- [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/)
- F#

Вообще довольно много языков поддерживают лямбда-выражения и замыкания, и позволяют писать в функциональном стиле (Ruby, Python, Go).

Comment: Недавно я изучал Objective-C. Начал использовать его лямбда-вычисления и замыкания (блоки), и только потом узнал термин "Функциональное программирование" . Пожалуй, буду выбирать из Closure и Scala (из тех, что на базе JavaVM).

Comment: javascript :). А вообще, учитывая наличие учебников -- scheme(язык) и sicp/htdp -- учебники. (Заодно там и по императивному программированию немало)

Comment: Недавно появился еще один язык на базе JVM - Kotlin.